# Jira Greenhopper Statistic gadget can't be configured "invalid field value"

Tags: jira, burndowncharts, jira-agile

My Greenhopper version is 6.0.1.

When I trying to add Greenhopper statistic gadget into my dashboard, I found that I can't configure it since the "field" drop down gives me no options. When I try to save the configuration, I got the error below:

[image: configuration error]

Answer (score 0):

Refer this URL https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Using+the+Agile+Classic+Statistics+Burndown+Chart+Gadget

You need to configure the statistics field https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Configuring+Statistics